# Как сделать клик в Toolbar по кнопке навигации?

Tags: java, android, actionbar, android-toolbar

не работает

```
activity.findViewById(R.string.abc_action_bar_up_description).performClick();
```

я сетаю в activity

```
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для того чтоб сделать клик по кнопке навигации которая находится в toolbar надо сделать следующее:

**Добавить текст в кнопку навигации**

```
toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription("up");
```

**После найти его следующим способом**

```
final ArrayList<View> outViews = Lists.newArrayList();
        activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar).findViewsWithText(outViews, "up", View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        outViews.get(0).performClick();
```